# OpenCL matrix vector multiplication code gives correct and incorrect solutions from run to run

Tags: opencl, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am working on OpenCL code for sparse matrix operations and I find that it works when the code including the kernel is executed once or twice. But every few runs the answer is slightly off. Here is the very simple kernel I am using:

```c
__kernel void dsmv( int N, __global int * IA,
                    __global int * JA, __global float * A,
                    __global float * X, __global float * Y){

    int IBGN, ICOL, IEND, ii;
    ICOL = get_global_id(0);

    if(ICOL < N)
    {
        IBGN = JA[ICOL]-1;
        IEND = JA[ICOL+1]-1-1;

        for (ii = IBGN; ii <= IEND; ii++)
        {
            Y[IA[ii]-1] +=  A[ii]*X[ICOL];
        }
    }
}
```

I can also post the fortran code that uses this kernel. I am using FortranCL.

What could cause the multiplication to give different answers from run to run?

Comment: Can you give a little more information on the meanings of your variables?  I don't have very much sparse-matrix multiplication experience.  Particularly I'm wondering about the IA and the JA matrix.  Otherwise it looks like a straightforward Y = AX multiplication.  Thanks!

Comment: The JA matrix points to the start of columns in IA and A. IA is array of row indices. A stores the non-zero values. I realize there are more efficient ways to handle the memory and matrix format but I want to get this version working before I experiment with that.

Comment: The only thing that I see could cause undefined behaviour is "Y[IA[ii]-1] += ", can you guarantee no two work units will ever access the same elements of Y? If not, then it's likely you have a race condition going on. Also, it's just my humble opinion but the code could really use better variable names.

Comment: I think my problem is that I CANT guarantee no two work units access the same element in Y. I think I may need to do something like on page 46 of this pdf http://mec.usc.edu/sc10/tutorial/SC10Tutorials/docs/M13/M13.pdf. Also I forgot to mention the extra -1 for IBGN and IEND are because the arrays are indexed from 1 in fortran.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
Y[IA[ii]-1] +=  A[ii]*X[ICOL];
```

It seems that two work items may increment the same memory location, so there is a potential race condition here, and since `+=` is not an atomic operation this is a problem.

Unfortunately you can't use the built-in `atomic_add` instead because it doesn't support floats, but `atomic_cmpxchg` does, so you can use it to implement a floating-point atomic add - or just [look at this existing implementation of an atomic add for floats](http://suhorukov.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html).